# How to increment the number within the file name each time a new file is created?

Tags: java

Hi there I am currently writing a method in Java where I am trying to create new files but I need those files not to be of the same name, but rather of incrementing name values, like so:

- /Users/Myself/Desktop/myFile0.xml
- /Users/Myself/Desktop/myFile1.xml
- /Users/Myself/Desktop/myFile2.xml
- /Users/Myself/Desktop/myFile3.xml

So I have tried to do the following in my code, but I do not understand why when I call the file within the for each loop ( to create a new one) the number does not increment?

```
public void pickFolder() throws Exception {

    chooserFolder.setDialogTitle("Specify your save location");
    chooserFolder.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);

    int numbers = 0;
    chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File("myFile" + numbers++ + ".xml"));
    chooserFolder.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("xml file", "xml"));

    int userSelection = chooserFolder.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        for (File file : files) {

            chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File(chooserFolder.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()));


            fileToSave = chooserFolder.getSelectedFile();
            if (fileToSave.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File is created!");
                fileToSave = chooserFolder.getSelectedFile();

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File already exists.");
            }

            System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers variable should be static;

```
public static int numbers = 0;

public void pickFolder() throws Exception {

chooserFolder.setDialogTitle("Specify your save location");
chooserFolder.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);

chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File("myFile" + numbers++ + ".xml"));
chooserFolder.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("xml file", "xml"));

int userSelection = chooserFolder.showSaveDialog(null);
if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    for (File file : files) {

        chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File(chooserFolder.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()));


        fileToSave = chooserFolder.getSelectedFile();
        if (fileToSave.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File is created!");
            fileToSave = chooserFolder.getSelectedFile();

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File already exists.");
        }

        System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());

    }
```

That way whenever you call pickFolder()-either you create a new instance or use the same instance- your numbers variable stays the same for every instance.

Comment: This  can be true too, because you would be calling the method again and again will will reset the number to zero and start from there again.

Make numbers variable static and also an class level variable

Comment: What does your getSelectedFile method looks like?

Comment: And after "chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File("myFile" + numbers++ + ".xml"));" line could you add "System.out.println(chooserFolder.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();" What does the print statement gives you?

Comment: getSelectedFile() is a method from JFileChooser,  and the print statement gives me:      /Users/Maiwand/IdeaProjects/BFC_GUI/myFile0.xml      , now this is fine for creating the first output file, but my issue is that the rest of the files have to have the same path but just the number before the .xml, to be incrementing.

Comment: Try calling pickFolder() method more than once, check out whether the print statement is incrementing the numbers variable. If the variable is being incremented, then you should suspect something is wrong with your for loop or your files list.

Answer (score 1):

That will be because you are appending it to a string "something" + 1 would be string concatenation in java.

Try something like this :

```
chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File("myFile" + (numbers++) + ".xml"));
```

This will make sure the number is incremented and then replaced with corresponding value.

Comment: There is no difference between what the OP posted (`"myFile" + numbers++ + ".xml"`) and your answer (`"myFile" + (numbers++) + ".xml"`) - they have the same meaning and behave exactly the same. The OP *wants* string concatenated so the first line of your answer doesn't make much sense.

Comment: yea i figured @arkantos answer is correct it seems. Thanks though